# Displaying different Launch Images based on IOS Version

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a situation causing me to have a need to support two different launch images for Portrait orientation on iPads as the views will be different depending on the IOS version.

I'm developing iPad/iPhone app that supports a UISplitViewController as the root window when the device is an iPad.  In IOS 5.0, supports the master view controller being displayed in split view while in portrait mode by responding "NO" in the shouldHideViewController UISplitViewControllerDelegate method.  In IOS 4.2, this method is not called and thus the Master View Controller is not displayed in Portrait orientation.  Instead, it is a popover presented when a Nav button is pressed.

Is there a way to create a single version of the application (from an iTunes customer perspective) that includes the appropriate launch image based on IOS version?

The iPhone App Programming Guide within the Advanced Tips and Tricks section describes how different launch images can be specified based on platform and device, but no IOS version as so: key_root-platform~device

Another post's answer indicated that I may be able to solve a similar problem by creating multiple targets to support multiple versions.  Is it possible to create multiple targets and upload them to Apple as a single application and have them distribute the appropriate binaries based on version? Any tips on how would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking for. Your best bet is to come up with some launch image that's not trying to be a faithful reproduction of what your home screen is.

Comment: Well technically that is what Apple recommends, so he should be applauded for trying, but yeah - it's okay to make your startup page a more simplified version of the screen - you could just show the header bar and an empty content region with no buttons or divider.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks for the super quick reply.
I think in the end I'll create an initial view controller that displays a background image of the startup detail view and another image that looks like the IOS 5 master.  For IOS4, I'll animate the fake master to shrink into the button.  It will be a good visual clue for the customer on what to do next.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just show the split view with the popover/sidebar closed in landscape view? That way it will look much the same for iOS4 and iO5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by creating a custom splash screen. Then you can perform a runtime check and load the appropriate image based on the iOS version. I have seen custom splash screens before (eg animated splash screens).

I think you would overide startupImageWithOrientation:, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373985/how-do-i-rotate-custom-splash-screen-on-ios) more for info.

As for your question about having multiple targets be one app, the answer is no.

Comment: Let me give this a try and post back my results.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think I'm stuck on the fact that my launch image is displayed before I have a chance to invoke other views.  BTW - The startupImageWithOrientation seems to be a method created as part of the example, and not an IOS method that could be overridden.  Let me know if I missed something. Thanks.